# Why is the equation of normal to the curve is x=10/9?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, parametric

```
    I have x = t^2 +1 and y = 3t^2-2t, These are the Parametric Equations. 
    dy/dx = 3-1/t.
    I already let dy/dx = 0
   3-1/t = 0
   3t-1=0
    t=1/3 

   sub t = 1/3 into x and y respectively
     x = (1/3)^2+1
       = 10/9
     y = 3(1/3)^2 - 2(1/3)
       = -1/3

     Coordinates of turning point(10/9,-1/3)

   I don't know how to solve the equation of the curve? According to the solution the equation of 
   normal to the curve is x=10/9. So how can I find the equation of normal to the curve?
```

Comment: Since you have found $t$, now find dy/dx.

Comment: since t = 1/3,                                                                                                                 
                    dy/dx = 3/ 1/(1/3)                                                                                                                                        
                             = 3-3=0

Comment: The equation of normal in which point is asked? In the point $(10/9,-1/3)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your condition of dy/dx = 0, you have determined that the *tangent* to the curve is a horizontal line passing through (10/9, -1/3) i.e. y = -1/3.
Thus, the normal (line perpendicular to the tangent) at that point is x = 10/9. 
Really, you have completed all the steps necessary beside the final step of interpreting the question.

Comment: how you know tangent to the curve is y=-1/3?

Comment: @Big_Smoke Well, you are trying to find the point where dy/dx = 0 right? That means the gradient at that point is 0, so the tangent is a horizontal line. And the only horizontal line that crosses (10/9, -1/3) is the line y = -1/3.